# Angular Modal not opening

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal dialog that won't open correctly through an html page that is appearing through ng-view and routeprovider. The modal works in index.html, but when you click the link Chicken and then the dialog from the chicken page, the dialog outputs incorrectly. Also for some reason in plnkr routeprovider isn't working so maybe someone can point out that issue as well.  works on my computer, but not in the plnkr for some reason.

plnkr.co/edit/bYhgAAe9QK8kp4Kt3l5b?p=preview

working in index.html
[image]

chicken-recipe.html

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Modal not opening with correct Height and Width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933779/angular-modal-not-opening-with-correct-height-and-width) and [Opening Modal Dialog in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902118/opening-modal-dialog-in-angular)

Comment: The post were never answered and I'm still experiencing the issue so if  you have any suggestions on my issue then I'd love to hear them. Someone asked from Angular Modal not opening with correct Height and Width to create a plnkr and I did, but he never responded and that was the end of that. So it's still an issue.

Comment: Problem is not solved posting multiple question. Delete duplicates (or they will be marked as one and closed anyway) or edit and rephrase your issue to attract answers. Problem statement should be clear and well structured with minimal code to reproduce the issue. You can search for existing plunks including `routeprovider` to help get you going (use google or [go here](http://plnkr.co/users/mikkoviitala)).